# Unable to connect to Integration service through SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created a `SSIS Package` and now want to deploy it, for that I am required to create the `Integration Service Catalog`,so I have `SQL Server Evaluation` Set up in that when I m trying to connect the integration service, I am getting following error,

> Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer
>   "RESHMAJADHAV" 
>       failed with the following error: "Access is denied."
>       By default, only administrators have access to the Integration Services service. 
>       On Windows Vista and later, 
>       the process must be running with administrative privileges in
>       order to connect to the Integration Services service. 
>       See the help topic for information on how to configure access to the service.

[image]

Also I have observed that my instance for `SQL Server Evaluation edition` is `RESHMAJADHAV\SQL_SERVER_EVALU` but when I am trying to connect this server, then this option is not shown under `Integration Services` as shown below,

[image].

I am unable to sort this out, since I am entirely new to this, please explain what can be the solution.

Please make a note, I also have sql server express edition ,but since it doesn't support to create the SSIS Integration service catalog then I installed the SQL Server Evaluation edition .

Also when I am trying to connect via SQL Database as shown in below image,

[image]

then while creating the integration service catalog, it is given the following error

> Password validation failed.
>       The password doesn't meet the requirements of password of the password filter DLL.
>       Change database context to SSISDB.

One fact I have observed, I don't know whether it is related or not but when I am trying to enter password for my system, then also it's giving same error that password doesn't meet the requirement and also when while installing the SQL Server edition, it gave the same error, no doubt my password was very strong and fulfill all the requirements of strong password, currently I am trying to run my SQL Server with windows authentication mode and also I have tried to disable the strong password policies from the administrative tools but it's totally futile....any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I researched little bit and then I came to know it was actually the problem of **HP Security Tool Manager service of HP Laptop** which was messing with the password of system,SQL Setup and catalog of Integration Service,I uninstalled it from PC and now my problem is resolved..

Answer (score 6):

Go to all programs 
Click on Microsoft SQL Server 2012 folder
Right click on SQL Server Management Studio
Click on Run as Administrator

This should take care of problem for now. (With this you need to always repeat the same process). To avoid this every time and for a more persistent solution you need to get permission(s). Please do the following process and you should be good.

In previous versions of SQL Server, by default when you installed SQL Server all users in the Users group had access to the Integration Services service. When you install the current release of SQL Server, users do not have access to the Integration Services service. The service is secure by default. After SQL Server is installed, the administrator must grant access to the service.

To grant access to the Integration Services service

1. Run Dcomcnfg.exe. Dcomcnfg.exe provides a user interface for modifying certain settings in the registry.
2. In the Component Services dialog, expand the Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config node.
3. Right-click Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 11.0, and then click Properties.
4. On the Security tab, click Edit in the Launch and Activation Permissions area.
5. Add users and assign appropriate permissions, and then click Ok.
6. Repeat steps 4 - 5 for Access Permissions.
7. Restart SQL Server Management Studio.
8. Restart the Integration Services Service.

(Source MSDN)

I hope this will help

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you both the op and solution poster.

Answer (score 1):

look like you don't have a admin privilege.
so start->sql server->right click->run as administrator
it might solve !!!

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear whether this is due to your windows password or the SSISDB encryption password http://fendy-huang.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/sql-server-2012-integration-services.html.

I suggest you think of a very long complicated password with a mixture of upper, lower and punctiation like this:

```
~~AgFcDeUk17aP9%3(5#hY,lTSs9+
```

and put that into the encryption field when creating the catalog. If that doesn't get around your error, try changing your windows password to that. The only way to solve thedr things is divide and conquer. Once you know which password is the issue you can attack it further.

Comment: @ElectricLlama... No strong password is proving to be useful..whatever I enter it just says,password doesnot meet the requirement of password filter DLL

Comment: Can you try disabling complex passwords under Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Account Policies -> Password Policy and see if that helps. If oyou need more detailed instructions on how to do this, search against your OS.

Comment: @ElectricLlama.. I have already disabled the complex password policy but still the issue prevails.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty much out of ideas now. Just to clarify your only problem at this stage is that you are unable to create the catalog. All that other stuff is not really relevant.

Comment: @ElectricLlama.. actually creating catalog is my main aim but I am unable to do so, I did the same setting sql setting on other system and I was successful in creating catalog in integration service on another respective system, so I came to conclusion that might be I am facing problem with my system regarding the password issue.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions here worked for me.

Here is what I found: I recently installed local SQL Server and Analysis Services instances for development. After this is when I started to have issues with my SSMS client connecting to Integration Services on other servers. I was getting errors such as:

1. Connecting to the Integration Services on the computer failed with "Access is denied: By default, only administrators only have access to the Integration Services service"
2. Connecting to the Integration Services on the computer failed with "Class not registered"
3. Connecting to the Integration Services on the computer failed with "The specified services does not exist as an installed service"

I tried re-installing SSMS v18.12.1 as well as a v19.0.1 and these issues still persisted. Even running SSMS as administrator.

I found that by going to the feature selection for the local SQL Server instance I just installed and adding the Integration Services feature to it that my issue was then resolved and I could connect to Integration Services again on other servers again.

[image: SSIS Feature]